# Error to installing the library of FIELDimageR

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I am trying to install the FIELDimageR library, I follow the recommendations indicated on [Github](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR#instal), I have tried to install it in the three ways indicated in the install section:

form 1

```
install.packages("FIELDimageR")
```

form 2

```
devtools::install_github("filipematias23/FIELDimageR")
```

form 3

```
setwd("I:/Datos_R/Demo/y2023L/ConteoPlantasR")  
unzip("FIELDimageR-master.zip") 
file.rename("FIELDimageR-master", "FIELDimageR")
shell("R CMD build FIELDimageR")
install.packages("FIELDimageR_0.3.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

However, and none have worked for me, I get the following error:

[image]

The version of R that I am using is the following:

[image]

I have also tried the recommendations in this link: About the [FIELDimageR category](https://community.opendronemap.org/t/about-the-fieldimager-category/4130/18), but nothing has worked.

If someone has already gone through this problem and put it to a solution and could help me please, since I have not found the solution.

I followed the recommendations indicated on [Github](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR#instal), and this [FIELDimageR category](https://community.opendronemap.org/t/about-the-fieldimager-category/4130/18), i hope can install this library in my pc, and that it works well.

Comment: the error message lists a bunch of packages that are not currently installed. What happens when you install them and then try to install this package?